# ¿Como cambiar la resolución de la imagen en una aplicación en ejecución Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un problema. Cuando trato de capturar una foto requiero que la aplicación ejecute la configuración para bajar la resolución de la cámara ya que al momento que el dispositivo posee una alta resolución se detiene la aplicación continuación es mi código de ejemplo:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Nombre Carpeta Almacenamiento");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Nombre Carpeta Almacenamiento/" + codigo_img + ".png";
codigo_img = obtener_fecha();
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "Nombre foto " + codigo_img + ".png");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
onClosed(cameraIntent);
```

Comment: Te da error? o que?

Comment: Tengo una aplicación desarrollada al momento de ejecutar la acción de tomar una fotografía en un dispositivo de gama alta se detiene el aplicativo, cuando bajo la resolución de la cámara de este funciona correctamente. La ayuda que necesito es como bajar la resolución de la cámara dentro del código de Android sin que el usuario sepa que se bajo la resolución.

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228365/how-to-capture-low-resolution-picture-using-android-camera